# Find the most accessed images

Tags: linux

I'm considering moving over all images we serve on our site to Amazon S3 to help with our server load. Instead of just dumping every single photo over to S3, I was wondering if it was possible to somehow track on the server which files are most accessed?

We're using Linux (CentOS to be specific) and I have access via SSH. Any tips?

Comment: How are the images being accessed ?#

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache, and you have enabled logging, then run your log files through a log analyser, something like AWStats, but other analysis tools exist

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Its up to you whether you want to leave the log files on the server and analyse them there, or ship them somewhere. Really depends on security, and performance capacity.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about acccess via web server then apachetop is tool that should meet your expectations. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following one-liner will give overview about how many times each file was accessed by your server:

```
awk '{print $7}' /path/to/apache/logfile | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n -k1,1
```

I assume that Common Log Format (CLF) is used so path to resource is located in 7th column. If you're interested only in particular format (jpeg) filter it with grep. In case your logs are logrotated (probably are) use zcat to decompress and concatenate them:

```
awk '{print $7}' <(zcat /var/log/apache/*.gz) | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n -k1,1
```